# Assigning function to function pointers

Tags: c, function-pointers

I worte a test program to understand callback functions and function pointers.The program is given below.

My question is while assigning

```
cb_display = (void*)display_struct;
```

I have to cast the function to a `void*`. Why is this required even when the return type of function is void?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    int a;
    char b[16];
}myst_t;

void (*cb_display)(void*);

void display_struct(myst_t *st){
    fprintf(stdout, "a -> %d b -> %s \n",st->a,st->b);    
}

int main()
{
    myst_t myst;
    myst.a = 789432;
    strncpy(myst.b,"helloabcd",9);

    cb_display = (void*)display_struct;

    cb_display(&myst);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The cast invokes undefined behaviour. `void *` can only be converted to/from an _object pointer_, not a function pointer. If you do it right, thre is no need for a cast either. Get your types right!

Comment: The return types match however the argument types differ (`void*` vs. `myst_t*`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cb_display = (void*)display_struct;
```

is actually also not valid in C. Don't do it. You cannot assign a `void *` to a function pointer.

To fix your issue declare your function pointer as:

```
void (*cb_display)();
```

It means it matches a function that return no value and takes an unspecified number of parameters. You then don't need any cast. Also please note as it was pointed by Olaf in the comments that a function declarator with `()` while valid is an obsolescent C feature.

Of course if you will only pass functions like `display_struct` with a `myst_t *` parameter, you can also declare `cb_display` as: `void (*cb_display)(myst_t *);`

Comment: I was about to ask wht the empty parameter list means :) thanks :)

Comment: I could also specify `void (*cb_display)(myst_t*)` as the signature of the function pointer?

Comment: @liv2hak Yes, it's the best option. Actually the assignment with no conversion at all must work well, but I'm not sure if it's an undefined behavior or not.

Comment: @EldarDordzhiev do you mean `void (*cb_display)();` and assignment with no cast? -> valid and specified behavior.

Comment: omitting `void` for an empty argument list (non-prototype declarator) is actually an [obsolencence](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.11.6p1) legacy construct and should not be used. `void (*cb_display)(void);` is the correct form. It is in general aq very dangerous declaration. The correct form here would be as you edited to have the correct argument types.

Comment: @Olaf not correct. C marks it as an obsolescent feature for function definitions only. And please not that `void (*cb_display)(void);` and `void (*cb_display)();` have different meanings here.

Comment: @ouah: Please read the paragraph. It is the declarator, not just the definition. (I'm well aware they have different semantics). But the empty parenthesis is legacy and inhibits type checking by the compiler. If you need variable arguments, an elipsis is the better way, but that is not necessary here anyway.

Comment: @ouah I mean when we just assign with no conversion `cb_display = display_struct;`. Is it an UD?

Comment: @Olaf fair enough, I answered from memory I didn't read your link. Added an edit in my answer.

Comment: @EldarDordzhiev: The **cast** invokes UB (do you mean this with "UD"?), as I commented on your question. If you get the types correct, as ouah's last parapraph shows, it should be fine. **General rule: do not cast, unless you have to and you REALLY know why and are sure about ALL implications.** (sorry for yelling, but there is no bolder-than bold;-)

Comment: @EldarDordzhiev `cb_display = display_struct;` but what it is the declaration of `cb_display` in this example?

Comment: @Olaf I got what you told about the cast, but I'm asking what does will happen if `cb_display` is defined like in the OP's question `void (*cb_display)(void*);`?

Comment: @EldarDordzhiev it's not valid with `void *` cast and it's also not valid without the cast, the two function types are different.

Comment: @ouah Yeah, thanks. I think it's weird as pointer types in C are all identical.

Comment: @EldarDordzhiev: Sorry, I thought you were OP. Why don't you just try and see what the compiler states (warnings enabled, of course - never run compiler without them!).

Comment: @Olaf Of course the first thing I did was compiling it and I *got* a warning. But it seems strange to me because the implicit conversion from *any pointer type* to `void*` is ok.

Comment: "... as pointer types in C are all identical" Where did you get this nonsense? An `int *` is certainly different from a `char *`, etc! And function pointers are even more different than object pointers. It's just that all _object pointers_ can be converted to/from `void *` - the universal object pointer. Yet, functions are **no** objects in C. This is the reason you should aviod `void *` whereever possible and use properly typed pointers. With great flexibility (of the language) comes great responsibility (of the programmer).

Comment: Passing functions that are not exactly `void(myst_t *);` will cause undefined behaviour, so I'd suggest that the prototype be used in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Changing void (*cb_display)(void*);

To typedef void (*cb_display)(void*);

May work.